# Error when previewing Wagtail page and getting related inlines

Tags: wagtail

I'm getting errors when previewing Wagtail pages, but they're fine when published and viewed live. My set-up is something like this:

```py
from django.db import models
from modelcluster.fields import ParentalKey
from wagtail.core.models import Orderable, Page
from wagtail.snippets.models import register_snippet

@register_snippet
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)

class ArticleAuthorRelationship(Orderable, models.Model):

    author = models.ForeignKey('Author',
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                related_name='articles')

    page = ParentalKey('ArticlePage',
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                related_name='authors')

class ArticlePage(Page):

    def get_authors(self):
        """Returns a list of Author objects associated with this article."""
        return [a.author for a in self.authors.all().order_by('author__name')]
```

In a template for an `ArticlePage` I call `self.get_authors()` to get a list of authors. This works fine if the article is 'live', or if I call the same method on the object in the shell, but when previewing the page I get this:

```
File "/Users/phil/Projects/myproject/myapp/articles/models/pages.py", line 551, in get_authors
  return [a.author for a in self.authors.all().order_by('author__name')]
File "/Users/phil/.local/share/virtualenvs/myproject-zPWVWoxf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/modelcluster/queryset.py", line 467, in order_by
  sort_by_fields(results, fields)
File "/Users/phil/.local/share/virtualenvs/myproject-zPWVWoxf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/modelcluster/utils.py", line 19, in sort_by_fields
  items.sort(key=lambda x: (getattr(x, key) is not None, getattr(x, key)), reverse=reverse)
File "/Users/phil/.local/share/virtualenvs/myproject-zPWVWoxf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/modelcluster/utils.py", line 19, in <lambda>
  items.sort(key=lambda x: (getattr(x, key) is not None, getattr(x, key)), reverse=reverse)
AttributeError: 'ArticleAuthorRelationship' object has no attribute 'author__name'
```

I'm stumped - I don't understand what's different about previewing a Wagtail page compared to viewing it normally. Something odd in modelcluster?

Comment: Viewing and previewing a page differ in that in the latter case, the models and relationships aren't persisted to the database so you can't do `self.authors.all()` in preview mode since no author exist. Wagtail use `django-modelcluster` to go around some of those limitations. Try to have a look at [`ParentalManyToManyField`](https://github.com/wagtail/django-modelcluster#many-to-many-relations).

Answer (score 6):

Yes, this is a limitation of the `django-modelcluster` module. In order for Django queryset methods such as `order_by` to work on in-memory relations that don't match the real database state (which is the case when previewing, as well as a few other situations such as viewing old revisions), modelcluster has to "fake" the operations that would normally be done through a SQL query. There are some limitations to how well the "faking" works, and some operations (such as raw SQL queries) will realistically never be possible.

The lack of support for `order_by` through a foreign key is a known limitation: https://github.com/wagtail/django-modelcluster/issues/45

Until this is fixed, a workaround would be to surround the query in a `try`/`except AttributeError` block and fall back on the unordered list.

Comment: Ah, thanks - I doubt I'd have figure out that cause myself. I owe you a beer or beer-equivalent gasman!

Comment: For anyone finding this... I belatedly realised I actually wanted to sort those Author snippets by the `sort_order` field, so that they match the order in which they're put in the admin. Because this isn't a foreign key (which `author__name` involves) this works on Preview too.