# "'Root' value must be an integer." when previewing a Wagtail Page

Tags: wagtail

In my [Wagtail](https://wagtail.io) site I have a way to add a list of "linked pages" to a Page, to show a list of related pages, articles, etc:

```py
from django.db import models
from modelcluster.fields import ParentalKey
from wagtail.core.models import Orderable
from wagtail.admin.edit_handlers import PageChooserPanel


class LinkedPage(Orderable):
    target_page = models.ForeignKey('wagtailcore.Page',
                                    null=True,
                                    blank=False,
                                    on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                                    verbose_name='Page',
                                    related_name='+')

    panels = [
        PageChooserPanel('target_page', [
                                    'articles.ArticlePage',
                                    'myapp_core.ContentPage',
                                ]),
    ]

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        ordering = ['sort_order']

class ContactPageLinkedPage(LinkedPage):
    host_page = ParentalKey('myapp_core.ContactPage',
                                related_name='linked_pages')
```

And then I can get a list of publicly-viewable linked pages from the `ContactPage` model:

```py
from wagtail.core.models import Page

class ContactPage(Page):
    # ...

    def get_linked_pages(self):
        public_pages = Page.objects.live().public()

        pages = self.linked_pages.filter(target_page__in=public_pages)

        return [lp.target_page for lp in pages]
```

This all works fine when viewing the page normally. But when trying to preview Contact Page I get a ValidationError:

> ["'Root' value must be an integer."]

This occurs from the line in `get_linked_pages()` that starts `pages = ...`. [Here's the traceback.](http://dpaste.com/1180WZN)

I'm *guessing* this might be a modelcluster-related issue, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54326493/error-when-previewing-wagtail-page-and-getting-related-inlines) I had a while back, but I haven't worked out how to get round it.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a proper answer, but just as a temporary fix, I've change the `get_linked_pages()` method (and similar ones) to be like this:

```py
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from wagtail.core.models import Page

class ContactPage(Page):
    # ...

    def get_linked_pages(self):
        public_pages = Page.objects.live().public()

        try:
            pages = self.linked_pages.filter(target_page__in=public_pages)
        except ValidationError:
            return []

        return [lp.target_page for lp in pages]
```

Obviously, this is far from perfect - no linked pages will be displayed in the preview at all, so it's not a great preview. But at least the rest of the page can be seen for now.